# Variables passed to url_for within an email link not working

Tags: python, flask, url-routing

I am setting up a registration feature for my flask application. When a user requests to register, I send an email to my admin account and would like to approve or deny their request.

When I send the email, the username, email and password given by the registration form are passed into the html and can be displayed. However when I try to move these variables along in a link created with 'url_for' they are unobtainable.

This is the email my admin account receives:

```
<p>{{ form.username.data }} has requested registration authorization.</p>
<p> Their information is as follows,</p>
<p>Username: {{ form.username.data }}</p>
<p>Email: {{ form.email.data }}</p>
<p>Password: {{ form.password.data }}</p>
<p>
  To register this user:
  <a href="{{ url_for('auth.register_user', username=form.username.data,
             email=form.email.data, password=form.password.data, _external=True) }}">
    click here.
  </a>
</p>
<p>-ADCo Inventory</p>
```

The username, email and password are all displayed correctly here.
And this is the auth.register_user html, where I am simply trying to show the username and password for the time being, which doesn't work.

```
{% extends 'base.html.j2' %}

{% block content %}
<h2> Register {{ username }}</h2>
<h2>pass: {{ password }}</h2>

{% endblock %}
```

Here is the route for auth.register_user if it helps any:

```
@auth_bp.route('/register_user', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register_user():

    form = RegistrationForm()

    return render_template('register_user.html.j2', form=form)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have passed the data via get request like below:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('auth.register_user', username=form.username.data,
             email=form.email.data, password=form.password.data, _external=True) }}">
```

So to access to username for example, you need to use request.args like below:

```
username = request.args.get('username', '')
```

Comment: I have updated my code so it has your suggestion: `username = request.args.get('username', '')
    email = request.args.get('email', '')
    password = request.args.get('password', '')
    if username and email and password:
        render_template('register_user.html.j2', form=form, username=username,
                        email=email, password=password)` But it still won't render {{ username }}

Comment: This link in the browser is similar to this /register_user?username=example&&.. ?

Comment: Yea, and I checked to make sure those variables were being set and the the template within the 'if' statement is being launched. It's the correct template with the correct variables being passed in.

Comment: I tried passing in a dummy variable, key='Hello', and even that won't show up

Comment: It turns out I was missing a 'return' statement before the render_template. Sorry for the confusion! Thanks again for being so helpful.